# Using boost::lambda to copy a container

Tags: c++, boost, boost-lambda

I'm here learning how to use boost::lambda. One question I have is about member function calling. It's just a test, and I'd like to do this with boost::lambda, as there are, obviously, half a million ways to copy the elements from one container to another container.

I have a `list<int>` which has 3 elements:

```
std::list<int> a;
a.push_back(2);
a.push_back(3);
a.push_back(4);
```

And a `vector<int>`:

```
vector<int> b;
```

I'm trying to do the following: for each element in a, push it back in b. Here's my shot:

```
std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), (b ->* (&std::vector<int>::push_back))(_1) );
```

The problem is that it's not accepting the member function call, telling:

`no match for ‘operator->*’ in ‘b ->* &std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back’`

I tried some other ways, but they didn't work either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), bind(&std::vector<int>::push_back, &b, _1));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use Boost.Phoenix with is a better implementation of lambda facilities in C++ and already has lazy version of std containers methods.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/spirit/phoenix/doc/html/index.html

Phoenix is currently hidden inside Spirit but it is planned to become a first class boost citizen in 1.47 which is due soon.

Comment: Hmm, very interesting. Thanks for the advise. Will it kick boost::lambda out of boost?

Comment: Not yet, the plan is to slowly deprecate it as soon as phoenix 3 includes some corner cases from lambda.